# Spring mvc and tiles integration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles2

I wanted to use multiple tiles

```
<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
      p:definitions="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs/templates.xml" />
```

but not able to understand how should is pass the multiple tiles.xml files

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs/templates.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs/templates1.xml</value>
            ... Keep adding the no. of xml you want as values
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: with p:definitions tag

Comment: @ashishchaurasia - And why only with the `p:definitions` tag? It's not necessary to use the `p` namespace to declare the definitions.

Comment: i am facing the issue with this..   cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for 
  element 'list'.
 - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [list]

Comment: @ashishchaurasia - I'm guessing there is some conflict with namespaces. [Refer this](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/spring-mvc-and-apache-tiles-integration-example/#3_Spring_application_context_configuration_for_Tiles) to make sure the namespaces and beans declared are proper.